# Android L: Google Play Services crash (Google+ Sign-In)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-5.0-lollipop

I am creating a new app and targeting the `android-L` version. The app requires a `Google+ Sign-In` but when i press the sign-in button it crashes without any StackTrace, but just the `Report-OK` dialog.

Google Play Services version in project: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'`
Nexus 5 Play Services: The latest update available.

Anyone else noticed the same behavior or found any workaround?

Edit:Logcat addition

```
10-06 07:37:34.844  20945-20945/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 20945
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.login.LoginActivityTask}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar$NavButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar$NavButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:629)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar.onCreateView(SourceFile:78)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1704)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1143)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5177)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:361)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:60)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:53)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:49)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:45)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.login.LoginActivityTask.onStart(SourceFile:153)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1217)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5736)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar.onCreateView(SourceFile:78)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1704)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1143)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5177)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:361)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:60)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:53)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:49)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:45)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.login.LoginActivityTask.onStart(SourceFile:153)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1217)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5736)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/auth_setup_wizard_navbar_ic_back.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020086
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2363)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2265)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:743)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:834)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar$NavButton.<init>(SourceFile:184)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar.onCreateView(SourceFile:78)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1704)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1143)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5177)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:361)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:60)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:53)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:49)
            at com.google.android.setupwizard.util.b.<init>(SourceFile:45)
            at com.google.android.gms.auth.login.LoginActivityTask.onStart(SourceFile:153)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1217)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5736)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPath.parsePath(VectorDrawable.java:892)
            at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VPath.inflate(
```

Comment: Turn off the logcat filter or catch bug report. Stacktrace has to be somewhere. :)

Comment: Does it work when you change `5.2.08` to `5.0.89`?

Comment: @AlexLockwood no, it didn't work!

Comment: What version of the support library are you using in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: @AlexLockwood compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'

Comment: Have you tried `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1`?

Comment: IDK if it makes a difference, but I got it working using a Nexus 7 (2013)... not sure if there are issues with the Nexus 5 version or not.

Comment: @AlexLockwood i am going to try but i recall i had another problem with that support library version, give me a min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the following version of the support library to your gradle dependencies:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

Comment: I immediately accepted and i hope it will help others too! Thank you once again :)

Comment: Hello again! Play services started crashing again! With the 6.1.11 version and the 21.0.0-rc1 when trying to connect on the Drive API and start the resolution for user sign-in it crashes with the same errors!

Comment: Perhaps only 5.0.89 works with the Dev preview for now?

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with the exact log error you are receiving.

Comment: It's the same log all around again!